# how to do category regression

Tags: multiple-regression

I have a set of data which contains students first term gpa, final gpa, their age, race, state and so on, I need to predict student's final gpa based on the others, my problem is how to convert race and state into numbers, I can't use dummy variables because there is 8 race and 20 states

Comment: Why can't you use dummy categories? I would have thought that almost all statistical software will do this for you. e.g. in R you could just have _race_ and _state_ as two factors, with each level being a string (letters), e.g. _white_, _black_, _purple_; _texas_, _virginia_ etc, and as long as the software recognises these are factors (usually automatic if you've got strings in the data) it will automatically convert them into dummy variables in the model?

Comment: @JupiterM104 can u tell me how do they convert 8 race into dummy variables because I am not using any statistical software, my assignment is to build my own code in C or Java

Comment: Assignment, eh? Sounds like you need a [tag:self-study] tag here. ;)

Comment: Sorry, that's well beyond my skills. However, it may help you to look at the model design matrix produced by a stats package when you give it some dummy data relevant to your needed model, and then try and make some code to do the same thing for any data. e.g. in R create dummy data (gpa, cont1 - random continuous variable, race & state), setup model formula (f1) and examine resulting model matrix: gpa <- rnorm(12); cont1 <- rnorm(12); race <- rep(c("white","black","purple"),4); state <- rep(c("a","b","c","d","e","f"),2); f1 <- formula(gpa ~ -1 + cont1 + race + state); model.matrix(f1)

Answer (score 4):

As long as you have enough observations I see no reason why you cannot enter race and state as a set of indicator variables. Here is one brief explanation on how to do that: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/dummy.htm

Comment: the problem is I have 8 race and 20 state, is that means I need to create 160 degree of freedom

Comment: No, only 7 for race and 19 for state. 26 degrees of freedom is often (but not always) not a problem. The large number of parematers you report would be the result of an interaction between race and state.